# Why is Firefox's task manager showing such different numbers that the system task manager?

Tags: mac, firefox

Per screenshot: my firefox tells me that tabs are using around 200mb of memory, but activity monitor is telling closer to 10x that amount.  What's going on here? 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Comparing the OS task manager figures against Firefox's performance page is an apples-to-oranges comparison. At the OS level, Firefox is managing its threads and processes in a very different way to how a user may perceive it, Put simply, a thread in Task Manager doesn't equate to one web page in the browser, and so on. In addition, the `about:performance` page doesn't give you any data about resources used by the core browser itself, as a matter of simplicity (there's not much you as a user can do about it).

If you want to see a more honest, but *extremely verbose* breakdown of how Firefox is managing its memory, then try out `about:memory`.